# not able to clear out an array in javascript

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am getting error when I try to clear out array `selectedCaseComments` in `showFeedDetail` method called from `connectedCallback` and `caseComments` and `prevSelectedCommentId` are getting populated from parent component.

`js file`

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
export default class LwcTspNotificationPage extends LightningElement {
    @api caseComments;
    @api prevSelectedCommentId;
    @track selectedCaseComments = [];
}

  connectedCallback() {
        Promise.resolve().then(() => {
             this.showFeedDetail(this.prevSelectedCommentId);
        });
}

showFeedDetail(selectedCommentId){
        let caseFeed = this.caseComments.filter(cseComment => {return cseComment.Id === selectedCommentId});
        if('caseComments' in caseFeed[0]){
            this.selectedCaseComments = caseFeed[0].caseComments;
        } else {
            this.selectedCaseComments.length = 0;
        }
}
```

`let caseFeed = this.caseComments.filter(cseComment => {return cseComment.Id === selectedCommentId});` this gives result like below:
[image]

As shown in the image if there is no property named `caseComments` in the array, I am trying to clear out `this.selectedCaseComments.length = 0;`, this gives error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'length'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify incoming data from an @api variable. This happens when you first assigned `caseFeed` to a value from `this.caseComments`, then later access `this.selectedCaseComments` to try and modify that array. You need to either copy the original array, or just create a new array.

## Copy Array

```
this.selectedCaseComments = [...caseFeed[0].caseComments];
```

## Create New Array

```
this.selectedCaseComments.length = [];
```

JavaScript passes objects by reference unless you copy the object, but the original object was read-only. You can see that effect with this code:

```
var x1 = { y: { z: 5 } }
var x2 = x1.y;
x2.z = 10;
console.log(x1.y.z); // outputs 10, not 5.
```

To fix this problem, you'd also do the same thing (but with an object):

```
var x1 = { y: { z: 5 } }
var x2 = { ...x1.y }
x2.z = 10;
console.log(x1.y.z); // Outputs 5
console.log(x2.z); // Outputs 10
```

Note that `...` is a shallow copy, so if you need to access any further child elements, those must also be copied somehow.

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead with `...` to create a copy of original array.